# How does SumoLogic Automatic Timestamp Parsing work?

Tags: sumologic

How does SumoLogic *automatic* timestamp parsing work? Does it parse a line of log output and stop at the first occurrence of what appears to be a timestamp? What formats does it support?

I am aware that you can [specify an exact format](https://service.sumologic.com/help/Understanding_Time_Stamps.htm) though I'm curious what default behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

The Sumo collector has a list of Regexes that match potential timestamps. It then stops at the first match. Formats similar to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html are usually supported, in addition to some epoch formats of 10, 13 digits (with or without up to 3 fractional digits).